# FastScrolling recyclerView with PagedListAdapter<Object, RecyclerView.ViewHolder> crashing when scrolled fast Why?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components, pagedlist, android-jetpack

My dao

```
@Dao
public abstract class UserDao {
  @Query("SELECT * FROM Users GROUP BY locality,fullName")
  public abstract PositionalDataSource.Factory<Integer, User> getUserLocalityGrouped();
}
```

As suggested in [**`Google I/O video`**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BE5bsyGGLf4&t=16m24s) i used `PositionalDataSource.Factory<Integer, User>` for `fast scrolling recyclerView`.

> But `getItem(position)` is `null` in `PagedListAdapter` when the user uses the fast scroll. Why ?

**NOTE** :- If the user *doesnt* use the fast scroll mechanism and uses the `general scroll` of recyclerView the app doesnt crash.